# Laravel-5.3 : Updating session not working properly

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.3

I'm using database driver to store sessions. When I update the payload, the views, wich depend on the datas into the payload, don't update.

Into my view, I often have things like that:

```
@if( Session::get('quicktrade') == 'Client' )
    <li class="@if ($coreData['navParent'] == 'quicktrade') active open @endif">
        <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="ico-quicktrade-{{Session::get('left_menu')}}"></i>
        <span class="title">QUICK[TRADE]</span>
        <span class="arrow @if ($coreData['navParent'] == 'quicktrade') open @endif"></span>
    @if ($coreData['navParent'] == 'quicktrade') <span class="selected"></span> @endif
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            @if( Session::get('quicktrade_evaluation') == 1 )
            <li class="@if ($coreData['navChild'] == 'evaluation') active @endif">
                <a href="{{ url('/quicktrade/evaluation') }}">
                NOUVELLE ÉVALUATION</a>
            </li>
            @endif
            @if ( Session::get('quicktrade_liste') == 1 )
            <li class="@if ($coreData['navChild'] == 'liste') active @endif">
                <a href="{{ url('/quicktrade/liste') }}">
                LISTE DES VÉHICULES</a>
            </li>
            @endif
            @if ( Session::get('quicktrade_statistiques') == 1 )
            <li class="@if ($coreData['navChild'] == 'statistiques') active @endif">
                <a href="{{ url('/quicktrade/statistiques') }}">
                STATISTIQUES</a>
            </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </li>
@endif
```

This make the menu to show or not options depend on the session.
All the datas are added to the payload during the LogSuccesfulLogin event.
So, if the user logout then login, I got no problem when I do some changes in the users table.

The problem is when the session is active and the user don't logout. If I do some changes, the view will stay the same as before.

In my user controller there is what happen:

```
$user = User::with('acces')->find($user->id);

$sessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
foreach ($sessions as $session) {
    $payload = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));
    $payload['oneaction'] = $user->acces->oneaction;
    $payload['oneaction_type'] = $user->acces->oneaction_type;
    if ($user->acces->oneaction == 'Client') {
        $payload['oneaction_clients'] = $user->acces->oneaction_clients;
        $payload['oneaction_list'] = $user->acces->oneaction_list;
        $payload['oneaction_creator'] = $user->acces->oneaction_creator;
    } else {
        $payload['oneaction_clients'] = 0;
        $payload['oneaction_list'] = 0;
        $payload['oneaction_creator'] = 0;
    }
    //dd($payload);
    $payload = base64_encode(serialize($payload));
    DB::table('sessions')->where('id', $session->id)->update(['payload' => $payload]);
}

$sessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
foreach ($sessions as $session) {
    $payload = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));
    //dd($payload);
}
```

As you can see in the code above, there is 2 `dd()`. Both show me that the changes are done properly. When I reload the page, ther is no change in the left menu.
I tried to do a `php artisan view:clear` right after the sessions have been updated, but the problem persist.
The only way I'm able to make this work, it's to delete all sessions of the user into the table. I don't want to go this way, so what am I missing? Why updating session don't work as I expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your session gets probably lost because your response does not contain the session-cookie. In laravel this is done via the [AddQueuedCookiesToResponse](https://github.com/illuminate/cookie/blob/master/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php) middlware which is kicked off in your [HTTP-Kernel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php). But since you are dump and dying somewhere in your controller, you are preventing this middlware from running.

Please note that this is just a guess, there could be other reasons why your cookie is getting lost. Check your kernel and maybe also your [config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#configuration) and ensure that you can see your cookie in your [http response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie).

Comment: If I understand well, the session is stored into the client side when user login. Since my app set() attributes during the LogSuccesfulLogin event, even if I change the payload on the database, this doesnt change the data on client side, because the token are still matching and client don't refresh the data. So, now I got 2 choice. Deleting all sessions of the users when I change his rights, or find a way to change the payload on every request? Is that right?

Comment: I changed set the code where I change the payload into `/* */` and added this line `$sessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->delete();`. It do the job, I don't really like how it do it. It generate a new session without logout the user. I'll do thing  this way until I can figure how to change the payload on client side without deleting every sessions.